# Time Range in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

The result of the query:[my query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5kDp.png)

```
select distinct information.ID, information.Name,information.Time AS OvertimeOff 
From Information
where information.Time >='18:00:00' AND information.Time <='20:00:00';
```

That is my query. My table has no value that is between by the given range. And there's no result. So, what I need is, if there is no match in the range, I need to set that value of the column as '00:00:00'. How can I do that in the query?

Comment: If you copy/paste your query please note there is a spelling error: distinct

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Ah Yeah. I mistyped it here. Sorry. But really, that is my problem. Can you please help me.?

Comment: Also, what is A? you didn't alias it anywhere.. Please provide more information about your expected output

Comment: It's the server in C# I'm using.

Comment: @MharkieAndryelleBeringuel The standard C# toolchain does not come with a database server.

Comment: @Dai I mean, the built in database server in visual studio professional.

Comment: @MharkieAndryelleBeringuel Visual Studio does not come with a database server either - excepting Visual Studio 2008 which installed SQL Server 2005 Express by default. Please provide more clarifying details.

Comment: @Dai Yes.I'm using VS 2010 actually and already installed SQL Server Express. You're right. Sorry.. I'm still a newbie about programming stuffs.. hihi. Thank you. Pls how can I do that.?

Comment: What should happen there is matching records for `>=` and there is no matching records for `<=`

Comment: The result would be for example, the columns are ID, Name and OvertimeOff and its values are: 11112345, Mharkie Andryelle, 20:00:00. because time 20:00:00 is matched for >= if there's 20:00:00 existed in the data. but if none, there's no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Following our discussion in the comments, You need something a bit more sophisticated then a simple case expression. My suggested solution involves the use of a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), as well as a case expression and a where clause:

```
;WITH cte As
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM Information
    WHERE Time >= '18:00:00' AND Time <= '20:00:00'
)

SELECT DISTINCT information.ID, 
   information.Name,
   CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte WHERE cte.Id = information.ID) THEN
       '00:00:00'
   ELSE
       information.Time 
   END AS OvertimeOff 
FROM Information
WHERE 
    (
    information.Time >= '18:00:00' 
    AND information.Time <= '20:00:00'
    )
OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte WHERE cte.Id = information.ID);
```

Breakdown:

- The cte is simply used to shorten the sub queries (since it's the
  same in the case expression and in the where clause.
- The `NOT EXISTS` part of the where clause ensures you only get records with
  '00:00:00' if there are no records with the time between '18:00:00'
  and '20:00:00'.
- The case expression now tests if there is a record
  for the id with the time in the range, and returns that time. If not,
  it returns  '00:00:00'

### First version

Assuming I understand the question correctly, you need to remove the condition from the where clause and put it inside a [case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression in the select clause.
Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT information.ID, 
       information.Name,
       CASE WHEN information.Time >='18:00:00' AND information.Time <='20:00:00' THEN
           information.Time 
       ELSE
           '00:00:00'
       END AS OvertimeOff 
FROM Information;
```

Comment: It really worked! You really helped me a lot. But my problem is when I tried putting a value in the table time 20:00:00, the value 00:00:00 still shown even though, 20:00:00 already exist in the table. I only want to see 20:00:00 without the 00:00:00. I only want to see the second row. Please.

Comment: So you want to get the rows that fits the condition, but if there are no rows that fits it you want a row with fake data (i.e '00:00:00')?

Comment: Yes @Zohar Peled, if there's no rows that fits the condition, only the fake time or data, '00:00:00' will be displayed.

Comment: It really worked great.! You're a savior! I have a hard time combining two common table expressions. I have a filter too about Overtime On too, like if the time is 16:00:00 to 18:00"00, it will display base on the time that fits the condition but if not, it will display 00:00:00 too. Can you please show us how? You really helped me a lot.

Comment: That seems like it should be a new question. anyway, to combine 2 cte you need to separate them with a comma: `;with cte1 as (...), cte2 as (...)`